# Stardand context menu in Python TKinter text widget when mouse right button is pressed

Tags: python, menu, popup, tkinter, contextmenu

I'm working on Windows XP, with Python 2.6.x and TKinter. Using a text widget in the app, but the standard popup menu (cut, copy, paste, delete, select all) is missing. How to make it appear?

Comment: Right-clicking for a context menu, as well as what appears on such a menu if one appears is not widely standardized. On platforms that support it there many be a convention for certain applications (like editing text). The `tkinter` API is platform independent, so if you want this functionality I believe you'll have to write (or find) code that implements it or something close to what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way, thanks to [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/30084-rlght-click-menu-missing-most-tk-apps#post111478). I made some modifications. At the bottom part there's a minimal `main` to try it.

```
from Tkinter import *

def rClicker(e):
    ''' right click context menu for all Tk Entry and Text widgets
    '''

    try:
        def rClick_Copy(e, apnd=0):
            e.widget.event_generate('<Control-c>')

        def rClick_Cut(e):
            e.widget.event_generate('<Control-x>')

        def rClick_Paste(e):
            e.widget.event_generate('<Control-v>')

        e.widget.focus()

        nclst=[
               (' Cut', lambda e=e: rClick_Cut(e)),
               (' Copy', lambda e=e: rClick_Copy(e)),
               (' Paste', lambda e=e: rClick_Paste(e)),
               ]

        rmenu = Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)

        for (txt, cmd) in nclst:
            rmenu.add_command(label=txt, command=cmd)

        rmenu.tk_popup(e.x_root+40, e.y_root+10,entry="0")

    except TclError:
        print ' - rClick menu, something wrong'
        pass

    return "break"


def rClickbinder(r):

    try:
        for b in [ 'Text', 'Entry', 'Listbox', 'Label']: #
            r.bind_class(b, sequence='<Button-3>',
                         func=rClicker, add='')
    except TclError:
        print ' - rClickbinder, something wrong'
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()
    ent = Entry(master, width=50)
    ent.pack(anchor="w")

    #bind context menu to a specific element
    ent.bind('<Button-3>',rClicker, add='')
    #or bind it to any Text/Entry/Listbox/Label element
    #rClickbinder(master)

    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `rClickbinder` appears superfluous in this example above. Or I suppose you should call `rClickbinder(master)` before calling `mainloop()`?

Comment: @scorpiodawg You are right, I've edited the answer: rClickbinder is there because it's a useful method to enable context menu on every element of the listed types.

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would share my solution, based on several code snippets on stackoverflow. It includes a minimum application to test:

edit: class bindings might not work. Should that be the case use normal bindings and return "break" in the select_all functions.

```
import Tkinter as tk

if 1:  # nice widgets
    import ttk
else:
    ttk = tk

class EntryPlus(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        _rc_menu_install(self)
        # overwrite default class binding so we don't need to return "break"
        self.bind_class("Entry", "<Control-a>", self.event_select_all)  
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.show_menu)

    def event_select_all(self, *args):
        self.focus_force()
        self.selection_range(0, tk.END)

    def show_menu(self, e):
        self.tk.call("tk_popup", self.menu, e.x_root, e.y_root)

class TextPlus(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        _rc_menu_install(self)
        # overwrite default class binding so we don't need to return "break"
        self.bind_class("Text", "<Control-a>", self.event_select_all)  
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.show_menu)

    def event_select_all(self, *args):
        self.focus_force()        
        self.tag_add("sel","1.0","end")

    def show_menu(self, e):
        self.tk.call("tk_popup", self.menu, e.x_root, e.y_root)


def _rc_menu_install(w):
    w.menu = tk.Menu(w, tearoff=0)
    w.menu.add_command(label="Cut")
    w.menu.add_command(label="Copy")
    w.menu.add_command(label="Paste")
    w.menu.add_separator()
    w.menu.add_command(label="Select all")        

    w.menu.entryconfigure("Cut", command=lambda: w.focus_force() or w.event_generate("<<Cut>>"))
    w.menu.entryconfigure("Copy", command=lambda: w.focus_force() or w.event_generate("<<Copy>>"))
    w.menu.entryconfigure("Paste", command=lambda: w.focus_force() or w.event_generate("<<Paste>>"))
    w.menu.entryconfigure("Select all", command=w.event_select_all)        


if __name__ == "__main__":

    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            self.entry = EntryPlus(self)
            self.text = TextPlus(self)

            self.entry.pack()
            self.text.pack()

            self.entry.insert(0, "copy paste")
            self.text.insert(tk.INSERT, "copy paste")

    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: self.tk.call("tk_popup", self.menu, e.x_root, e.y_root) can be transformed into the more readable self.menu.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root). HTH

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gonzo's code and bluish `'<Control-c>',` my textwidget right button worked.
I don't have 50 reputations but I had a problem which I faced that the right button will trigger the function regardless of the location of the point clicked.
figured that out by:

```
    def show_menu(self, e):
       if e.widget==self.text:
          self.tk.call("tk_popup", self.menu, e.x_root, e.y_root)
```

Now only the right button's popup will be triggered when you click on text widget.

Answer (score 0):

To add function that deletes selected text in tkinter text widget, use:

```
def delete_highlighted_text():
    text_widget.event_generate("<Delete>")
```